# How can i disable or hide default cancel button in QFileDialog?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm trying to use `QFileDialog` as a widget, to use `QFileDialog` as a widget the final step for my is to disable the cancel button.

Have you an idea of how can i disable this button.

PS : I am using Qt 5.5.0

Comment: what are you trying to do?? why do you need to have it disabled???

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ First thanks for the response, I'm trying to use QFileDialog as a widget because Qt not provide file browser in a widget form and i need to disable it because it close the FileDialog and i don't want my user to have a useless cancel button.

Comment: To my knowledge QDialogs should not be used as widgets, they have own message pump.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to access the various standard buttons via the [`QDialogButtonBox`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialogbuttonbox.html) and, from there, do what you want with the `Cancel` button.

The following example code appears to works as expected...

```
QFileDialog fd;

/*
 * Find the QDialogButtonBox.
 */
if (auto *button_box = fd.findChild<QDialogButtonBox *>()) {

  /*
   * Now find the `Cancel' button...
   */
  if (auto *cancel_button = button_box->button(QDialogButtonBox::Cancel)) {

    /*
     * ...and remove it (or disable it if you prefer).
     */
    button_box->removeButton(cancel_button);
  }
}
fd.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

The [QFileDialog Class](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qfiledialog.html) doesn't seem to have any option for this.

However, you could make your own file browser using QTreeModel and QTreeView (It's not too difficult).

There is a tutorial on how to do just that [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M0PZDrDwdHM).

It would take a while to type out all the code (sorry, I'm a slow typer), but this tutorial should allow you to have the flexibility you need to do what you want to do.

I understand that this answer isn't exactly what you asked, but I hope it is a good alternative.

*EDIT: Accidentally pasted wrong link for QFileDialog Class*